# Seeking Javascript library for displaying and editing networks of nodes and edges

Tags: javascript, networking

This is my first question, so I hope I have asked it clearly.  Apologies in advance if it has already been answered and I just haven't managed to work out the right thing to search for.

I am looking for a Javascript library that I can use to create an application for interactively editing networks of nodes and edges.

Here a "node" is a point where at least three edges meet, and an "edge" joins two nodes, but might be a "polyline" in that it has multiple segments rather than being a straight line.  The positions of the elements (nodes and segments of edges) in the canvas are important (i.e. it's not just which nodes meet which edges).

The manipulations I need to be able to perform using the mouse and keyboard are:

- creating a new node
- deleting a node
- creating a new edge between nodes
- deleting an edge manipulating an edge by adding and removing segments (equivalently, adding and removing points along the edge)
- changing a point on an edge into a new node changing a node back into just a point along the edge
- dragging a point or a node so that the lines joined to it move along with it.

I also need to be able to zoom in and out.

I need to be able to access the data describing the network (i.e. positions of points, and relationship between lines and points), and serialize and deserialize it.

Overall I expect to have a few hundred nodes and a few thousand points along the edges between them.

I'm expecting to have to write a fair bit of code, but it would be good to do so on top of a suitable, "natural" framework.

I have found things that do part of what I need:

- Google My Maps allows editing of single polygons
- fabric.js has many useful manipulation features, but doesn't (as far as I can see) allow editing of the points along a polyline
- GoJS has editable polylines as part of its examples
- D3js looks hopeful, and has literally hundreds of examples, but none seems close to what I am trying to do - in particular it seems more useful for visualization than manipulation.

Any pointers gratefully appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please read the "how to ask a good question" first

Answer (score 1):

Here's most of your app: https://gojs.net/extras/splicing.html.  The complete implementation code is on the page -- just do a "View Page Source" browser command.  But I'll duplicate it here anyway:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Simple Splicing Sample for GoJS</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Splicing a new node into a selected link, and splicing out an existing node in the path of a link chain." />
  <!-- Copyright 1998-2018 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/gojs"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/goSamples.js"></script>  <!-- this is only for the GoJS Samples framework -->
  <script id="code">
    function init() {
      if (window.goSamples) goSamples();  // init for these samples -- you don't need to call this

      var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

      myDiagram =
        $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
          {
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
            // create a node upon double-click in background:
            "clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData": { text: "a new node" },
            "undoManager.isEnabled": true
          });

      myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
        $(go.Node, "Auto",
          { locationSpot: go.Spot.Center },
          new go.Binding("location", "location", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
          {
            selectionAdornmentTemplate:
              $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
                $(go.Panel, "Auto",
                  $(go.Shape, { fill: null, stroke: "dodgerblue", strokeWidth: 2 }),
                  $(go.Placeholder, { margin: 1 })
                ),
                $(go.Shape, "XLine",
                  {
                    isActionable: true,  // so that click works in an Adornment
                    width: 14, height: 14, stroke: "orange", strokeWidth: 4, background: "transparent",
                    alignment: go.Spot.TopRight,
                    click: function(e, shape) {
                      var node = shape.part.adornedPart;
                      spliceNodeOutFromLinkChain(node);
                    },
                    cursor: "pointer"
                  },
                  new go.Binding("visible", "", function(ad) {
                    var node = ad.adornedPart;
                    return maySpliceOutNode(node);
                  }).ofObject())
              )
          },
          $(go.Shape,
            {
              fill: "lightgray", strokeWidth: 0,
              portId: "", fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer"
            },
            new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
          $(go.TextBlock, "some text",
            { margin: 8, editable: true },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        );

      myDiagram.linkTemplate =
        $(go.Link,
          {
            relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true,
            reshapable: true, resegmentable: true,
            selectionAdornmentTemplate:
              $(go.Adornment,
                $(go.Shape, { isPanelMain: true, stroke: "dodgerblue", strokeWidth: 2 }),
                $(go.Shape, "PlusLine",
                  {
                    isActionable: true,  // so that click works in an Adornment
                    width: 16, height: 16, stroke: "green", strokeWidth: 4, background: "transparent",
                    segmentOffset: new go.Point(8, 0),
                    click: function(e, shape) {
                      var link = shape.part.adornedPart;
                      var p0 = link.getPoint(0);
                      var p1 = link.getPoint(link.pointsCount - 1);
                      var pt = new go.Point((p0.x + p1.x) / 2, (p0.y + p1.y) / 2);
                      spliceNewNodeIntoLink(link, pt);
                    },
                    cursor: "pointer"
                  })
              ),
            toShortLength: 1
          },
          new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
          $(go.Shape, { strokeWidth: 2 }),
          $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "OpenTriangle" })
        );

      function spliceNewNodeIntoLink(link, pt) {
        link.diagram.commit(function(diag) {
          var tokey = link.toNode.key;
          // add a new node
          var newnodedata = { text: "on link", location: go.Point.stringify(pt) };
          diag.model.addNodeData(newnodedata);
          // and splice it in by changing the existing link to refer to the new node
          diag.model.setToKeyForLinkData(link.data, newnodedata.key);
          // and by adding a new link from the new node to the original "toNode"
          diag.model.addLinkData({ from: newnodedata.key, to: tokey });
          // optional: select the new node
          diag.select(diag.findNodeForData(newnodedata));
        }, "spliced in node on a link");
      }

      function maySpliceOutNode(node) {
        return node.findLinksInto().count === 1 &&
          node.findLinksOutOf().count === 1 &&
          node.findLinksInto().first() !== node.findLinksOutOf().first();
      }

      function spliceNodeOutFromLinkChain(node) {
        if (maySpliceOutNode(node)) {
          node.diagram.commit(function(diag) {
            var inlink = node.findLinksInto().first();
            var outlink = node.findLinksOutOf().first();
            // reconnect the existing incoming link
            inlink.toNode = outlink.toNode;
            // remove the node and the outgoing link
            diag.removeParts([node, outlink], false);
            // optional: select the original link
            diag.select(inlink);
          }, "spliced out node from chain of links");
        }
      }

      load();
    }

    // Show the diagram's model in JSON format that the user may edit
    function save() {
      document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
      myDiagram.isModified = false;
    }
    function load() {
      myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <div id="sample">
    <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width:100%; height:400px"></div>
    <div>
      <button id="SaveButton" onclick="save()">Save</button>
      <button onclick="load()">Load</button>
      Diagram Model saved in JSON format:
    </div>
    <textarea id="mySavedModel" style="width:100%;height:300px">
{ "class": "GraphLinksModel",
  "nodeDataArray": [ 
{"key":1, "text":"Alpha", "color":"lightblue", "location":"-40 -10"},
{"key":2, "text":"Beta", "color":"orange", "location":"106 -58"},
{"key":3, "text":"Gamma", "color":"lightgreen", "location":"-8 105"},
{"key":4, "text":"Delta", "color":"pink", "location":"110 51"}
 ],
  "linkDataArray": [ 
{"from":1, "to":2, "points":[-15.5,-18.0,84.5,-50.9]},
{"from":1, "to":3, "points":[-35.7,5.1,-12.2,89.85]},
{"from":2, "to":2, "points":[116.7,-42.8,150.3,4.3,59.3,0.3,93.8,-42.8]},
{"from":3, "to":4, "points":[23,90.8,87,61.5]},
{"from":4, "to":1, "points":[87,41.6,-15.5,0.0]}
 ]}
  </textarea>
    <p>
      When a Link is selected it shows a green "+" button that when clicked creates a new Node and splices it into the link.
      It does that by reconnecting the existing link to the new node and creating a new link to go from the new node to the original
      destination of the selected link.
    </p>
    <p>
      When a Node is selected, if it has exactly one Link coming into it and exactly one Link going out of it,
      then it shows an orange "X" button.  When clicked it removes the node and the outgoing link and reconnects the incoming
      link to connect with the original destination of the outgoing link.
    </p>
    <p>
      All links are relinkable and resegmentable.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Double-click in the background to create a new node.  That's implemented by:

```
"clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData": { text: "a new node" },
```

Or Control-drag or Control-C/Control-V to copy the selection.

Drag from just inside the edge of a node in order to draw a new link to a node.  That's implemented by:

```
portId: "", fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer"
```

on the **Shape** in the **Node**.

Click on the text of a selected node in order to start editing it.  That's implemented by:

```
editable: true
```

on the **TextBlock** in the **Node**.

Each link, when selected, allows the user to either drag an end in order to reconnect it, or to add or remove points by dragging the middle handle(s).  That's implemented by:

```
      relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true,
      reshapable: true, resegmentable: true
```

on the **Link**.

Each link also has a custom selection **Adornment** that shows a green "+" button that creates a new node and splices it into the link:

```
            selectionAdornmentTemplate:
              $(go.Adornment,
                $(go.Shape, { isPanelMain: true, stroke: "dodgerblue", strokeWidth: 2 }),
                $(go.Shape, "PlusLine",
                  {
                    isActionable: true,  // so that click works in an Adornment
                    width: 16, height: 16, stroke: "green", strokeWidth: 4, background: "transparent",
                    segmentOffset: new go.Point(8, 0),
                    click: function(e, shape) {
                      var link = shape.part.adornedPart;
                      var p0 = link.getPoint(0);
                      var p1 = link.getPoint(link.pointsCount - 1);
                      var pt = new go.Point((p0.x + p1.x) / 2, (p0.y + p1.y) / 2);
                      spliceNewNodeIntoLink(link, pt);
                    },
                    cursor: "pointer"
                  })
              ),
```

Each Node that has exactly one Link coming into it and one Link going out of it (that is not the same Link) has a selection Adornment including an orange "X" button that allows that node to be spliced out of their path.  That is implemented as:

```
            selectionAdornmentTemplate:
              $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
                $(go.Panel, "Auto",
                  $(go.Shape, { fill: null, stroke: "dodgerblue", strokeWidth: 2 }),
                  $(go.Placeholder, { margin: 1 })
                ),
                $(go.Shape, "XLine",
                  {
                    isActionable: true,  // so that click works in an Adornment
                    width: 14, height: 14, stroke: "orange", strokeWidth: 4, background: "transparent",
                    alignment: go.Spot.TopRight,
                    click: function(e, shape) {
                      var node = shape.part.adornedPart;
                      spliceNodeOutFromLinkChain(node);
                    },
                    cursor: "pointer"
                  },
                  new go.Binding("visible", "", function(ad) {
                    var node = ad.adornedPart;
                    return maySpliceOutNode(node);
                  }).ofObject())
              )
```

Selecting a **Node** and the deleting it with the `Delete` key will not only delete the node but also all links connecting with it.

There's full support for undo and redo, of course.  That's implemented by:

```
"undoManager.isEnabled": true
```

Everything should work on touch devices, too, although I haven't tried it with this sample.

And serialization and deserialization is done by calling **Model.toJson** and **Model.fromJson** in the `save` and `load` functions:

```
document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();

myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value);
```

Of course you'll want to send and receive the JSON-formatted text to and from your server rather than showing it on the page in a <textarea>.