# How to insert node into polyline link in gojs, preserving positions of points in links either side of the new node

Tags: javascript, polyline, gojs

I asked a question on StackOverflow ([Seeking Javascript library for displaying and editing networks of nodes and edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803867)) and was pointed at the gojs splice sample.

This has got me a long way, so thanks for the answer, but I have run into a brick wall trying to get the behaviour I want.

The app I am trying to create is to edit the borders on a map:

- node = place where three or borders meet
- link = segment of border between two nodes.

Hence, the nodes and links are unlabelled (nodes are just small circles, links are just polylines).

I have attempted to adapt the splice sample (https://gojs.net/extras/splicing.html) appropriately.  The key features I need over and above what the sample does are:

- choosing exactly where to position the new node on the link between the existing ones
- preserving the shape of the polylines.

(The existing sample puts the new node equidistant between the existing ones and uses straight links.)

The user experience I have tried to create is this:  first, you select the link, so it gets its usual adornments; then you shift-click on one of the adornments at a point on the polyline and that point becomes the new node.

I have sought to do this by overriding methods of the LinkReshapingTool using the extension mechanism described at https://gojs.net/latest/intro/extensions.html (rather than creating a subclass).

Whatever I have tried, though, I can't get the polylines to stay.  By inspecting the diagram data model in the Chrome DevTools debugger after my code has run, it *appears* that it is correct (i.e. I can see the correct array of points in the links).  However, when I then allow execution to continue the links do not display as expected (they are straight), and if I subsequently look at the data model then the multiple points have disappeared and each link just has a start and end.

I have tried various things, without success, for example:

- deferring the splicing till after the tool has completed
- passing the points into the modified links in different ways (array *v* list *v* string)
- putting the processing into different overridden methods.

My current code is below.  Please excuse crass stylistic faux pas - I am not an experienced JavaScript programmer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  <!-- HTML5 document type -->
<!--
Adapted from splicing example from gojs.net
 -->
<html>
<head>
  <!-- use go-debug.js when developing and go.js when deploying -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.8.28/go-debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiagramDiv"
     style="width:400px; height:300px; background-color: #DAE4E4;"></div>

<script>
  var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

  // state variables to remember what to do after reshaping tool aborted
  var doSpliceNode     = false;
  var doSpliceIntoLink = null;
  var doSplicePoint    = null;
  var doSpliceIndex    = -1;  
  
  // diagram
  var myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
                     {
                       "undoManager.isEnabled": true
                     });
                     
  var tool = myDiagram.toolManager.linkReshapingTool;

  // Override doMouseDown on linkreshapingtool.  If user clicks on a handle with SHIFT pressed, want to insert
  // a new node at that point rather than use the default behaviour to (further) reshape the link, and moreover
  // want to retain the points in the link.  I.e. turn one of the points in the link into a new node.
  // (Existing gojs splicing example does not do this: it just puts a new node at the midpoint of the existing
  // link, with no regard to the points along the link.)
  tool.doMouseDown = function() {
  
    console.log("mousedown at (" + this.Fp.M + "," + this.Fp.N + ")");
    console.log(" on link from " + this.adornedLink.fromNode + " to " + this.adornedLink.toNode);
    console.log(" with shift pressed? " + myDiagram.lastInput.shift);

    
    var spliced = false;
    
    if (myDiagram.lastInput.shift)
    {
    
      // work out which of the points on the link was clicked
      var link   = this.adornedLink;
      var numpts = link.pointsCount;
      var i;
      var x = this.Fp.M; // @@TODO - by inspection in debugger this contains the X coord, but what's documented place to get this?
      var y = this.Fp.N; // @@TODO - ditto for Y coord
    
      for (i = 1; !spliced && (i < numpts - 1); i++)
      {
        if ((link.getPoint(i).x == x) && (link.getPoint(i).y == y))
        {
           console.log(" .. at point " + i);

           // Store off what to do.  (This used to be done inline - deferred to after as one of the things
           // to try to make it work.)
           doSpliceNode     = true;
           doSpliceIntoLink = link;
           doSplicePoint    = new go.Point(x, y);
           doSpliceIndex    = i;  
         
           spliced = true;
        }
      }
    }
    
    //if (!doSpliceNode)
    { 
      console.log(".. call base class doMouseDown");
      go.LinkReshapingTool.prototype.doMouseDown.call(tool);
    }
  }

  // Override doMouseUp as well.  If we had decided during mousedown to do the splice, then stop the tool now.
  tool.doMouseUp = function()
  {
    // First call base class
    go.LinkReshapingTool.prototype.doMouseUp.call(tool);
  
    if (doSpliceNode)
    {
      // Doing splice - stop tool
      console.log("STOP TOOL");
      this.stopTool();
      this.doDeactivate();
    }
  }  
  
  // Finally, override doStop to actually do the splice
  tool.doStop = function() {

    console.log("doStop");
    
    // First call base class
    go.LinkReshapingTool.prototype.doStop.call(tool);
  
  
    if (doSpliceNode)
    {
      // now splice the node
      console.log("splice node");
      spliceNewNodeIntoLink2(doSpliceIntoLink, doSplicePoint, doSpliceIndex);  // @@TODO make it respect points in existing link before and after
    }  
  
    // Reset everything
    doSpliceNode     = false;
    doSpliceIntoLink = null;
    doSplicePoint    = null;
    doSpliceIndex    = -1;  
  } 
    
  // Debug variable for inspecting later - not functional                    
  var debugLastLink = null;                  
                     
  // Model, node and links for this application.  Based heavily on https://gojs.net/temp/splicing.html and adapted as needed.
  
  var myModel = $(go.GraphLinksModel);
  
  myDiagram.nodeTemplate = $(go.Node,
                             "Auto",
                             new go.Binding("location", "location", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
                             $(go.Shape, "Circle", { width: 6, height: 6, strokeWidth: 0 }));
  
  
  
  myDiagram.linkTemplate =
        $(go.Link,
          {
            relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true,
            reshapable: true, resegmentable: true,
          /*  selectionAdornmentTemplate:     @@ COMMENT OUT - NOT NEEDED
              $(go.Adornment,
                $(go.Shape, { isPanelMain: true, stroke: "dodgerblue", strokeWidth: 2 }),
                $(go.Shape, "PlusLine",
                  {
                    isActionable: true,  // so that click works in an Adornment
                    width: 16, height: 16, stroke: "green", strokeWidth: 4, background: "transparent",
                    segmentOffset: new go.Point(8, 0),
                    click: function(e, shape) {
                      alert(e);
                      var link = shape.part.adornedPart;
                      var p0 = link.getPoint(0);
                      var p1 = link.getPoint(link.pointsCount - 1);
                      var pt = new go.Point((p0.x + p1.x) / 2, (p0.y + p1.y) / 2);
                      
                      // @@TODO - instead, find the position where the mouse was clicked and place the node there
                      // ... need to work out which segment of polyline this was in so as to calculate new lines
                      
                      // @@TODO - handle drag of node so that it just affects segments of lines immediately into it, rather than
                      // blatting over top of them

                      // @@TODO - what is object e and its components
                      
                      spliceNewNodeIntoLink(link, pt);
                    },
                    cursor: "pointer"
                  })
              ), */
            toShortLength: 1
          },
          new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),   // Use the points information from the linkDataArray initializer
          $(go.Shape, { strokeWidth: 2 })
        );

/*      function spliceNewNodeIntoLink(link, pt) {  // @@ original version no longer called
        link.diagram.commit(function(diag) {
          var tokey = link.toNode.key;
          // add a new node
          var newnodedata = { text: "on link", location: go.Point.stringify(pt) };
          diag.model.addNodeData(newnodedata);
          // and splice it in by changing the existing link to refer to the new node
          diag.model.setToKeyForLinkData(link.data, newnodedata.key);
          // and by adding a new link from the new node to the original "toNode"
          diag.model.addLinkData({ from: newnodedata.key, to: tokey });
          // optional: select the new node
          diag.select(diag.findNodeForData(newnodedata));
        }, "spliced in node on a link");
      }  */

      // Utility function used in one attempt to get this to work.  Initializers in nodeDataArray do it via an array of numbers,
      // so try that here.
      function toArray(nodelist)
      {
        var returnarray = new Array();
        var i;
        
        for (i = 0; i < nodelist.size; i++)
        {
          var pt = nodelist.elt(i);
          returnarray.push(pt.x);
          returnarray.push(pt.y);
        }
        
        return returnarray;
      }
      
      // Function to splice the new node into the link.  Parameters are
      // - link:  the link to splice into
      // - pt:    the point within the link to turn into a node
      // - index: index into existing polyline of that point
      function spliceNewNodeIntoLink2(link, pt, index) {
        link.diagram.commit(function(diag) {
          
          var oldlinkpointslist = link.points;
          var link1pointslist = new go.List(go.Point);
          var link2pointslist = new go.List(go.Point);
          var i;
          
          // Create new points list, from "from" node to new node to be added
          for (i = 0; i <= index; i++)
          {
            var point = new go.Point(link.getPoint(i).x, link.getPoint(i).y);
            link1pointslist.add(point);
          }
          
          console.log(link1pointslist);
          
          // .. and from new node to "to" node
          for (i = index; i < link.pointsCount; i++)
          {
            var point = new go.Point(link.getPoint(i).x, link.getPoint(i).y);
            link2pointslist.add(point);
          }

          console.log(link2pointslist);
          
          var tokey = link.toNode.key;
          // add a new node
          var newnodedata = { text: "on link", location: go.Point.stringify(pt) };
          diag.model.addNodeData(newnodedata);
          // and splice it in by changing the existing link to refer to the new node
          diag.model.setToKeyForLinkData(link.data, newnodedata.key);

          // ** NEW CODE
          // Code this was based on re-used the existing link, re-purposing it to go from "from" node 
          // to new node, so do the same, but give it a new points list.
          link.points = link1pointslist;    // @@TODO find out why this doesn't work    
                                            // ... actually it does, but something ditches the points later ...
                                            // so maybe I need to move this code to after the tool has really finished operating
                                            // by saving off the info and calling it in an override of the last tool method that
                                            // gets called (perhaps not - did this and it didn't work)
                                

          debugLastLink = link; // @@TEMP         
          
          // and by adding a new link from the new node to the original "toNode"
          // ** UPDATED to include the second new point list
          diag.model.addLinkData({ from: newnodedata.key, to: tokey, points: toArray(link2pointslist) });
          
          // optional: select the new node
          diag.select(diag.findNodeForData(newnodedata));
        }, "spliced in node on a link");
      }

      // not called at present
      function maySpliceOutNode(node) {
        return node.findLinksInto().count === 1 &&
          node.findLinksOutOf().count === 1 &&
          node.findLinksInto().first() !== node.findLinksOutOf().first();
      }

      // not called at present
      function spliceNodeOutFromLinkChain(node) {
        if (maySpliceOutNode(node)) {
          node.diagram.commit(function(diag) {
            var inlink = node.findLinksInto().first();
            var outlink = node.findLinksOutOf().first();
            // reconnect the existing incoming link
            inlink.toNode = outlink.toNode;
            // remove the node and the outgoing link
            diag.removeParts([node, outlink], false);
            // optional: select the original link
            diag.select(inlink);
          }, "spliced out node from chain of links");
        }
      }

 
  // Initialize modeldi 
  myModel.nodeDataArray = [
         { key: "1" , "location": "30 30" },
         { key: "2" , "location": "130 30" },
         { key: "3" , "location": "30 130" }
  ];
  
  myModel.linkDataArray = [ 
         { from: "1", to: "2", "points": [  30,30,  70,20, 100,40, 130,30 ] },
         { from: "2", to: "3", "points": [ 130,30, 100,80,  70,90, 30,130 ] },
         { from: "3", to: "1", "points": [ 30,130, 20,100,  40,70,  30,30 ] }
  ];
  
  myDiagram.model = myModel;
  
  
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Call **Link.findClosestSegment** to find the segment where the user clicked to insert a node.
- Don't splice in the new node in an override of **Tool.doStop**, because that will be called even if the user hit the Escape key to cancel the tool's operation.  Do it in either **doMouseDown** or **doMouseUp**, depending on the behavior that you want.  But **doStop** is a reasonable time to clean up the tool's state.
- I think it should work if you add the new Node and a new Link, connect them together properly, make sure the Node is at the right location, and only then set **Link.points** explicitly.  The TwoWay Binding on **Link.points** will save the points to the model.

The problem that you are encountering is that when you create a new Node it takes time to be measured and arranged and positioned.  Any one of those activities will invalidate the routes of all connected links.  And obviously connecting a link with a node will invalidate that link's route.  So you have to make sure everything is done in the right order.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried calling the splicing code from doMouseDown and from doMouseUp and neither worked, so the answer must be in your second bullet.  Please therefore can you elaborate on the API calls required to do this - in particular, what does it mean to connect things together properly?  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm still stuck.  I've tried changing the code so that the splicing action is called after everything has finished (using setTimeout()), and I have changed it so it explicitly removes the old link and adds a new node and the two links, but whatever I try the points property of the two new links objects is simply ignored.  For what it's worth, when I initially load the page, the network appears with straight line links between the nodes, and then suddenly change to have the "kinks" I have coded.  I wonder if that is relevant.

Comment: Problem appears to be solved by having the execution thread sleep (see https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-sleep/) for 100ms between adding the node and adding the links.  I guess there is a race condition somewhere.  I'll post my updated code once I've tidied it up a little.